# Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"

Tags: java

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture sonic;


@Override
public void create() {      
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sonic = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Sonic_walk.png"));

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(sonic, 50, 50);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

Then I get this error,

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:        
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: Sonic_walk.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: Sonic_walk.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
at com.me.mygdxgame.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:18)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:127)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: Sonic_walk.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:127)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:580)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
... 8 more
```

I do not under stand the error. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: As it says, it couldn't load the file `Sonic_walk.png`. What have you tried? Does the file exist?

Answer (score 0):

LiGDX cannot find the file, make sure it is in the right directory.

Also com.me.mygdxgame is intended as a filler for you to fill in and not to actually be used :P